# Terraform kubernetes_config_map --from-env-file

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, configmap, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am creating a kubernetes configMap using '--from-env-file' option to store the file contents as environment variables.

```
kubectl create configmap env --from-env-file=env.properties -n namespace
```

When I create a terraform resource as below, the created configMap contains a file, not environment variables.

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "env" {
  metadata {
    name = "env-config"
    namespace = var.namespace
  }
  data = {
    "env.properties"   = "${file("${path.module}/env.properties")}"
  }
}
```

How to create configMap with file content as environment variables using terraform-kubernetes-provider resource ?

Answer (score 4):

If `env.properties` looks like this:

```
$ cat env.properties
enemies=aliens
lives=3
allowed="true"
```

Then `kubectl create configmap env --from-env-file=env.properties -n namespace` would result in something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env
  namespace: namespace
data:
  allowed: '"true"'
  enemies: aliens
  lives: "3"
```

But what you're doing with Terraform would result in something more like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env
  namespace: namespace
data:
  env.properties: |
    enemies=aliens
    lives=3
    allowed="true"
```

Based on the [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/config_map.html) it appears that what you're looking for, i.e. some native support for `--from-env-file` behaviour within the Terraform provider, is not possible.

The `ConfigMap` format that you get doing it the Terraform way could still be useful, you might just have to change how you're pulling the data from the `ConfigMap` into your pods/deployments. If you can share more details, and even a simplified/sanitized example of your pods/deployments where you're consuming the config map, it may be possible to describe how to change those to make use of the different style of `ConfigMap`. See more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find sufficient info in the documentation to implement --from-env-file option. But, yes I know the other way, I can modify the usage of this configMap inside my deployment. Thanks.